# Extract data using REGEX

Tags: java, regex

May I know how to extract the following data using REGEX?

1) textA;textB;textC;textD

Extract "textA;textB;textC" aka parent of textD

2) textA;textB;textC;textD AB(numberA)

Extract "textA;textB;textC;textD" aka parent of AB(numberA)

3) textA;textB;textC;textD AB(numberA)
Extract "numberA" for comparison

currently implementation, i use java string function, which make it un-configurable. I suspect the user didn't give me the actual data and I need to change the function again in the near future. I hope to use regex to make the function configurable.

Answer (score 3):

1. `(.*);[a-zA-Z]+` - $1
2. `(.*) .*` - $1
3. `.* .*\((.*)\)` - $1 
   How to use regexes and groups: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups.shtml
   Example:

   ```
   String s = "textA;textB;textC;textD";
   Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(.*);[a-zA-Z]+");
   Matcher mt = pt.matcher(s);
   if(mt.matches())
       System.out.println(mt.group(1));
   ```

That prints: `textA;textB;textC`.
UPD: Because the pattern is not known, answer like 1)`textA;textB;textC;(textD)` is also true. When asking such questions, it is better to write pattern, even if you don't know regexes you can use words only.
UPD: thx for correction

Comment: care to explain a bit.. I tried using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html for testing It doesn't work.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think the 3rd regex is incorrect. I think it will match "AB(numberA)", while a match for "numberA" is requested. Shouldn't it be something like `.* .*\((.*)\)` - $1

Comment: for N° 3 : `".*\\(([A-Fa-f0-9 ,.]{1,128}).*\\)*"`extract the number (with basic format symbol) remove letters if no hexadecimals are waited and manage other symbols as you like to keep close to the correct transmitted String, you can also adapt size `{128}` to maximal length of number

Answer (score 0):

can simply use this?

```
String[] arr = "textA;textB;textC;textD AB".spilt("[; ]");
```

Comment: I can't customize it. You know Users?